# How to connect current transducer CKSR 6-NP with PIC18F4550 or easyPic3?

Tags: microcontroller

How to connect current transducer CKSR 6-NP with PIC18F4550 or easyPic3?
This transducer has ref pin . what are resistances and capacitors need to connect with PIC to get good results and Ref pin where I will connect. how connect this sensor with solar panel to read current it by ADC Pic.

Comment: More details are required before anybody can answer your question.  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What, exactly, is your current sensor? That part number isn't something that most of us are familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The [LEM CKSR 6-NP current sensor](http://www.lem.com/docs/products/cksr%20series.pdf) is an active voltage-output bipolar closed-loop Hall type with 2.5V out with zero current (assuming you don't override the internal Vref).

If you configure your ADC with 0-5V in you don't need anything else- connect the sensor output to the ADC input. That means your accuracy will be dependent on the 5V reference (which might be the power supply). If that's okay you're done. The voltage changes from Vref by +/-104.2mV/A for a single turn.

If you use a quality external ADC Vref (say 4.096V) you could divide that in two with a couple precision resistors, buffer it with a voltage follower and feed that into the Vref input of the LEM sensor to get slightly less range, but superior accuracy. Or use a separate 2.048V precision shunt reference and just connect it from Vref to ground (with whatever cap the reference manufacturer recommends). It has to work on ~600uA.

[image]

Maybe add an R-C low pass filter if that is appropriate for the types of signals you intend on measuring. The sensor has a 200kHz bandwidth which might be higher than you need or want. A 2K + 10uF filter would reduce the bandwidth to ~8Hz. That would be Rf and Cf in the above diagram.

Comment: I use microC compiler. I must to let my program 2kbytes because If increase instructions I will get massage Demo limit. So I will let my variables as int and current values  from transducer is small between 2.5v represent 0A and 4.5v represesnt 6A. MY power supply gave me 0-2A. I read 2.5v,2.6v,2.7v,2.8v from transducer when I putted output transducer as float, but when I want to read (solar panel) voltage sensor(voltage divider) and current transducer.I can not because number of instructions increase. How to solve this problem?